# Security of storing passwords with Passport and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using [Passport-Local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) to store my users password with MySQL db.
 But when I store the password, the string typed is stored as it is.
What are the best practices to store passwords with MySQL/Sequelize/Passport in terms of security?

Comment: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to not store user passwords. If you use passport, you should use something like passport-twitter, and store the Twitter user ID.

If you still want to store passwords, hash it with salting. I recommend [blowfish](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/blowfish), I use it when I need to store passwords.